# New string every time a loop runs

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, random, brute-force

Looking to prove a sibling wrong about how long it can take a computer to guess a specific string by using Brute Force even with the correct number of characters put in.  I can get the code to run but I cannot figure out how to get it to print a new string every time it runs.  I'm sure I'm over looking something simple.  Below are a couple examples of the code I've tried.

```
import string
import random

random=''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for n in xrange(5)])

while True:
   if random != "Steve":
      print(random)
   if random == "Steve":
      print("Found")
```

This will continually print the same string over and over.  I've also tried this without the `while` statement just the `if` and it doesn't seem to work.

I know enough that once `random` picks those 5 randoms characters it won't change until something makes it change but like I said I'm not sure how to do that.  I've tried moving `random` to different places but doesn't work I just get different error messages.

Can someone help me out.

Comment: You need to compute random within the loop

Comment: I have tried to put `random=''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for n in xrange(5)])' in the while statement but I keep getting the following error.                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/craig.walker/Desktop/new.py", line 9, in <module>
    random=''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for n in xrange(5)])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'

Comment: Change the name of your variable from `random` to something else and change it accordingly in the `while` loop, or change import from `import random` to `import random as rand` and use `rand.choice`. You are using a keyword as your variable name.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the [Weasel](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/courses/27615.mol/weasel.php) program, which will run a lot faster than brute force.

Answer (score 4):

```
random=''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for n in xrange(5)])
```

This doesn't create a new random string each time. At this point random is just a randomly generated string that doesn't change while your while loop runs. Referencing random doesn't create a new string, but rather just gets the first string your generated, since random is just a string in your memory not a function.

Move the random string creation into a function:

```
import string
from random import choice

def make_random():
    return ''.join([choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for n in xrange(5)])
```

Then run the loop:

```
while True:
    random = make_random()

    if random != "Steve":
        print(random)
    if random == "Steve":
        print("Found")
```

EDIT:

Switched `import random` to `from random import choice` because random (the variable) was overwriting random (the library) and throwing an attribute error when you try to call `random.choice`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems here. As @Primusa pointed out, your random generation should be moved inside your loop otherwise it'll only run once. However, your other problem is that you're importing `random` and you're also setting a variable to `random`. This is where your `NameError` is coming from. You've defined `random` to be a string, which works on the first iteration of your loop. However, on the second iteration, `random` won't have a function called `choice` declared for it because it's a string at that point. Rename your `random` variable or import the `random` package under an alias, like this:

```
import random as rnd
```

Comment: Thank you I was just about to post that I was still getting errors.  It was because I had the import random and a var named random and it was giving me a weird error.  Thanks its fixed now!

Comment: @CraigWalker No worries. I've done the same thing before :)